# refreshing the whole listview except the row which i selected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have dynamically created rows in my list view. 
On each row I have one radio button and one text view(text view displays a number)

The radio buttons are named  "Partial". When I click on a radio button a dialog box comes up which takes an integer input and updates the number on the text view.

I want only one radio button( "Partial" ) to be selected across all rows in my list view, so when I select one radio button, other radio buttons get unselected.

So, when a user selects "Partial" on one and there is a previously marked radio button as "partial", it should unselect the previous radio button and also reset the number mentioned to the previous one before updating through the dialog box . 
Here is what I have tried but did not get desired output.

```
// this is my adapter class
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Bills_model> checkboxClassArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Bills_model>checkedItemList;
    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;

    public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Bills_model> checkboxClassArrayList,ArrayList<Bills_model>chedItemList){
        this.context=context;
        this.checkboxClassArrayList=checkboxClassArrayList;
        this.checkedItemList=chedItemList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow_full_partial_paymentselection,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        final Bills_model checkboxClass = checkboxClassArrayList.get(position);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(checkboxClass.isChecked());
        holder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(checkboxClass.getTotal_amnt_afterdiscount()));
        holder.checkBox.setTag(checkboxClass);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checkboxClassArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        private RadioButton checkBox;
        private TextView amount;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbt_partial);
            amount=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_full_partial);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            amount.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.rbt_partial:

                    if(onRecyclerViewItemClickListener!=null)
                    {
                        final Bills_model tag = (Bills_model) v.getTag();

                        tag.setChecked(true);
                        onRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(),v);

                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
    public void setOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener onRecyclerViewItemClickListener){
        this.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener=onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
    }}



// this is my on click listener

   @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, View view)
    {
        final Bills_model checkboxClass;
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.rbt_partial:

                checkboxClass = (Bills_model) view.getTag();
                /**/
                if(checkboxClass.isChecked())
                {
                    Log.e("SDsd","Ddaerwerwerewrfgsd");

                    for(int i=0; i<bills_modelArrayList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        final Bills_model data = bills_modelArrayList.get(i);

                        if(data.equals(checkboxClass))
                        {
                            Log.e("SDsd","data_if"+data.getTotal_amnt_afterdiscount());
                            data.setChecked(true);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("SDsd","data_else"+data.getTotal_amnt_afterdiscount());
                            data.setChecked(false);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    Log.e("SDsd","data_else"+"elseeeeeee>?????");

                }
                /**/
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Select_Full_Partial_Activity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enteramount_partial);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                final EditText text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtamount_advanceamnt);

                TextView ok = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtok_advanceamnt);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        double amountToDeduct= Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
                        double amountenterd= Double.parseDouble(checkboxClass.getTotal_amnt_afterdiscount());

                        if(amountToDeduct>amountenterd)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Select_Full_Partial_Activity.this,"You are enterting amount greater than" +String.valueOf(checkboxClass.getTotal_amnt_afterdiscount()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            checkboxClass.setTotal_amnt_afterdiscount(""+amountToDeduct);


                        }

                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.show();
                break;
                case R.id.cb_full:
                break;
        }
    }
```

// above code is working fine for me but problem is that whenever i clicked in radio button previously selected radio button become unchecked but the the value which i enterd become same but i want to that the value should also change as it was previously.